# How can you print an item that is void** data in C?

Tags: c, stack, printf, void-pointers

While trying to build a test rig for a C stack I ran into problems in how to display it correctly. I have checked six books and they all have a method for push and pop to/from the stack, but none give an example of how you actually use the routines. Can someone show me the pattern, so I can write debug printf statements?

The call to pop uses this structure:

```
{ struct Element *next; void *data; }
```

The pop function is:

```
int pop ( tElement **stack, void **data )
```

How do I printf the data item.

Comment: You need to know the type of the item else that `void **` is useless to you (unless you just want to `%p` and print out the address).

Answer (score 4):

You can print out the pointer value:

```
void print_data (void **data) {
    printf("%p", data);
    if (data) printf(", *%p", *data);
}
```

Or, you can provide a callback hook to the user of the data structure to provide a printing function for you:

```
void pretty_print_data (void **data, void (*print_callback)(void **)) {
    printf("%p%s", data, (data ? "" : ": "));
    if (data) printf(", *%p: ", *data);
    if (print_callback) print_callback(data);
}
```

The programmer providing the callback knows what type the `data` should be:

```
void print_point (void **data) {
    if (data && *data) {
        point *p = *data;
        printf("(%d, %d)", p->x, p->y);
    } else {
        printf("nil");
    }
}
```